# Installing Ruby 1.9.3 on OSX 10.7.3 with RVM (make error)

Tags: ruby, makefile, rvm

I am have been trying to install Ruby via rvm on my Mac (OSX 10.7.3, with XCode 4.3.1) for 2 days now... I am getting an "error running make" every time I am trying. I could see many people have encountered the same problem, but so far what has worked for them hasn't for me (installing GCC, updating Xcode, readline related fixes, etc.).

Here is the make.log:

```
[2012-03-10 00:48:25] make 
CC = clang
LD = ld
LDSHARED = clang -dynamiclib
CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=write-strings -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=shorten-64-to-32 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration  -fno-common -pipe 
XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
CPPFLAGS = -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin11.3.0 -I./include -I.
DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace -install_name /Users/bryandufour/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib -current_version 1.9.1 -compatibility_version 1.9.1 -Wl,-unexported_symbol,_Init_* -Wl,-unexported_symbol,*_threadptr_*  -Wl,-u,_objc_msgSend   
SOLIBS =
linking miniruby
<internal:prelude>:1: [BUG] Bus Error
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0003 p:0002 s:0006 b:0006 l:000005 d:000005 TOP    <internal:prelude>:1
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:000ce8 d:000ce8 TOP   

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
<internal:prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

   See Crash Report log file under ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter or
   /Library/Logs/CrashReporter, for the more detail of.

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: ./miniruby

* Loaded features:

0 enumerator.so

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

make: *** [.rbconfig.time] Abort trap: 6
```

And the crash report:

```
Process:         miniruby [2844]
Path:            /Users/USER/*/miniruby
Identifier:      miniruby
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  gnumake [2831]

Date/Time:       2012-03-10 00:48:25.719 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.3 (11D50b)
Report Version:  9

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000103ea2ab7

VM Regions Near 0x103ea2ab7:
--> __TEXT                 0000000103e5e000-0000000104045000 [ 1948K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Users/USER/*
__DATA                 0000000104045000-0000000104061000 [  112K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  /Users/USER/*

Application Specific Information:
objc[2844]: garbage collection is OFF
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9a333ce2 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f17f7d2 pthread_kill + 95
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f170a7a abort + 143
3   miniruby                        0x0000000103e8e759 rb_bug + 185
4   miniruby                        0x0000000103f3dbe6 sigbus + 54
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f1d1cfa _sigtramp + 26
6   miniruby                        0x0000000103f9685e vm_exec_core + 2734 (vm.inc:494)
7   miniruby                        0x0000000103fa1e9e vm_exec + 94 (vm.c:1221)
8   miniruby                        0x0000000103fa1dd2 rb_iseq_eval + 402 (vm.c:1448)
9   miniruby                        0x0000000103f39258 ruby_process_options + 1432 (ruby.c:1098)
10  miniruby                        0x0000000103e929c0 ruby_options + 128 (eval.c:73)
11  miniruby                        0x0000000103e5f0e7 main + 71 (main.c:38)
12  miniruby                        0x0000000103e5f094 start + 52

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9a333df2 __select + 10
1   miniruby                        0x0000000103fb15e3 thread_timer + 371 (thread_pthread.c:1158)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f17d8bf _pthread_start + 335
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8f180b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000006  rcx: 0x0000000104193938  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000303  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x0000000104193960  rsp: 0x0000000104193938
   r8: 0x00007fff7de95fb8   r9: 0x00000001041934e8  r10: 0x00007fff9a333d0a  r11: 0xffffff80002d8220
  r12: 0x0000000104300028  r13: 0x0000000104295750  r14: 0x00007fff7de98960  r15: 0x00000001043fff50
  rip: 0x00007fff9a333ce2  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x0000000103fa8df0
Logical CPU: 0

Binary Images:
   0x103e5e000 -        0x104044ff7 +miniruby (??? - ???) <B6C1C835-8EA0-3BE9-BF1D-8323E0E4A6A3> /Users/USER/*/miniruby
0x7fff63a5e000 -     0x7fff63a92baf  dyld (195.6 - ???) <0CD1B35B-A28F-32DA-B72E-452EAD609613> /usr/lib/dyld
0x7fff8dda4000 -     0x7fff8ddaafff  libmacho.dylib (800.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <D86F63EC-D2BD-32E0-8955-08B5EAFAD2CC> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x7fff8ded2000 -     0x7fff8ded3ff7  libremovefile.dylib (21.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <739E6C83-AA52-3C6C-A680-B37FE2888A04> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x7fff8df7e000 -     0x7fff8dfccfff  libauto.dylib (??? - ???) <D8AC8458-DDD0-3939-8B96-B6CED81613EF> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
0x7fff8eb33000 -     0x7fff8eb34ff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (??? - ???) <5087ADAD-D34D-3844-9D04-AFF93CED3D92> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x7fff8f127000 -     0x7fff8f12efff  libcopyfile.dylib (85.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <172B1985-F24A-34E9-8D8B-A2403C9A0399> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x7fff8f12f000 -     0x7fff8f20cfef  libsystem_c.dylib (763.12.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <FF69F06E-0904-3C08-A5EF-536FAFFFDC22> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x7fff8fb6a000 -     0x7fff8fb6fff7  libsystem_network.dylib (??? - ???) <5DE7024E-1D2D-34A2-80F4-08326331A75B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x7fff90265000 -     0x7fff90269fff  libdyld.dylib (195.5.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <F1903B7A-D3FF-3390-909A-B24E09BAD1A5> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x7fff90275000 -     0x7fff902eaff7  libc++.1.dylib (19.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <C0EFFF1B-0FEB-3F99-BE54-506B35B555A9> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x7fff9061d000 -     0x7fff9061dfff  libkeymgr.dylib (23.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <61EFED6A-A407-301E-B454-CD18314F0075> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x7fff90d6c000 -     0x7fff90d99fe7  libSystem.B.dylib (159.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <7BEBB139-50BB-3112-947A-F4AA168F991C> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x7fff90ff1000 -     0x7fff90ffaff7  libsystem_notify.dylib (80.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <A4D651E3-D1C6-3934-AD49-7A104FD14596> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x7fff9163e000 -     0x7fff9164cfff  libdispatch.dylib (187.7.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <712AAEAC-AD90-37F7-B71F-293FF8AE8723> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x7fff917a7000 -     0x7fff917e2fff  libsystem_info.dylib (??? - ???) <35F90252-2AE1-32C5-8D34-782C614D9639> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x7fff91af7000 -     0x7fff91af8fff  libunc.dylib (24.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <C67B3B14-866C-314F-87FF-8025BEC2CAAC> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
0x7fff93096000 -     0x7fff93109fff  libstdc++.6.dylib (52.0.0 - compatibility 7.0.0) <6BDD43E4-A4B1-379E-9ED5-8C713653DFF2> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x7fff970c2000 -     0x7fff970cdff7  libc++abi.dylib (14.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <8FF3D766-D678-36F6-84AC-423C878E6D14> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x7fff970f8000 -     0x7fff970fafff  libquarantine.dylib (36.2.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <48656562-FF20-3B55-9F93-407ACA7341C0> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
0x7fff97907000 -     0x7fff97908fff  libdnsinfo.dylib (395.6.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <718A135F-6349-354A-85D5-430B128EFD57> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x7fff97922000 -     0x7fff97926fff  libmathCommon.A.dylib (2026.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <FF83AFF7-42B2-306E-90AF-D539C51A4542> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
0x7fff9793c000 -     0x7fff97941fff  libcache.dylib (47.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <B7757E2E-5A7D-362E-AB71-785FE79E1527> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x7fff97a13000 -     0x7fff97af7e5f  libobjc.A.dylib (228.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <871E688B-CF57-3BC7-80D6-F6476DFF109B> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x7fff97c3b000 -     0x7fff97c40fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (6.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <98ECD5F6-E85C-32A5-98CD-8911230CB66A> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x7fff98234000 -     0x7fff98235ff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (53.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <8BCA214A-8992-34B2-A8B9-B74DEACA1869> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x7fff98236000 -     0x7fff98253fff  libxpc.dylib (77.18.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <26C05F31-E809-3B47-AF42-1460971E3AC3> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x7fff984aa000 -     0x7fff984b2fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (??? - ???) <7749128E-D0C5-3832-861C-BC9913F774FA> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x7fff99513000 -     0x7fff99555ff7  libcommonCrypto.dylib (55010.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <A5B9778E-11C3-3F61-B740-1F2114E967FB> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x7fff9a315000 -     0x7fff9a31bff7  libunwind.dylib (30.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <1E9C6C8C-CBE8-3F4B-A5B5-E03E3AB53231> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x7fff9a31d000 -     0x7fff9a33dfff  libsystem_kernel.dylib (1699.22.73 - compatibility 1.0.0) <69F2F501-72D8-3B3B-8357-F4418B3E1348> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x7fff9a51e000 -     0x7fff9a528ff7  liblaunch.dylib (392.18.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <39EF04F2-7F0C-3435-B785-BF283727FFBD> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
task_for_pid: 0
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
task_for_pid: 0
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
task_for_pid: 5338
thread_create: 1
thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=54.6M resident=20.1M(37%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=34.4M(63%)
Writable regions: Total=75.0M written=676K(1%) resident=1396K(2%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=73.7M(98%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
MALLOC                             10.4M
MALLOC guard page                    16K
MALLOC_LARGE (reserved)             256K        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
STACK GUARD                           4K
Stack                              64.0M
__DATA                              680K
__LINKEDIT                         48.1M
__TEXT                             6644K
shared memory                        12K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             129.9M
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space    129.7M
```

I am a beginner in programming, and am not super familiar with the terminal yet (have been a PC user for many years), so please be indulgent :).

I hope you guys can help.

Enjoy the week-end ;).

Answer (score 2):

please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9651747/497756

I had no chance to prove if this patch helps for your issue - would be great.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I followed all the steps described in the post, but I unfortunately still run on the same issue... I start to feel hopeless...

Comment: please update to newer RVM and try with ruby-1.9.3-p194 - it has a lot better support for clang, you could also just install osx-gcc-installer and RVM would automatically use it to build ruby, which has higher chances of success.

Answer (score 0):

As separate solution (to my previous answer), you might switch back to osx-gcc-installer which is known to compile all rubies.

There were reported comparability issues between osx-gcc-installer and Xcode 4.2.1, but none for Xcode 4.3 (but it's so known usage together).

Apple removed standard GCC from Xcode 4.2 - from this point you can not compile MRI Ruby on OSX easily, osx-gcc-installer is a private build of the required tools including GCC - which has proven to work to compile Ruby.

The most reliable solution is to remove Xcode totally from disk restart computer and install osx-gcc-installer.