# How to uninstall XCode 4.3.1 from Mac OS X 10.7.3?

Tags: xcode, uninstallation

I can't install Ruby with XCode 4.3.1 and have been advised to downgrade to XCode 4.1. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to downgrade. Simply install the **Command Line Tools** from **Preferences > Downloads**.

If you still want to uninstall Xcode, then delete **Xcode.app** from the **/Applications** folder.

If you are talking about RVM (then check the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9651670/1207152)). But also update your question accordingly.