# Trouble installing ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I am looking to install ruby 1.9.3. I currently have ruby 1.9.2 installed

Mac  Os X
Xcode Version 4.3.2
I have dumped all the previous version of Xcode

I have read a ton of articles and I tried out the steps that are detailed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9651747/1392225

This is the error that I have

```
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #extracted to /Users/kai/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125 (already extracted)
WARN: Patch 'xcode-debugopt-fix-r34840.diff' not found.
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #configuring 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #compiling 
ERROR: Error running 'make ', please read /Users/kai/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/make.log
ERROR: There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

The error log seems to point to this

```
compiling readline.c
readline.c: In function ‘username_completion_proc_call’:
readline.c:1499: error: ‘username_completion_function’ undeclared (first use in this function)
readline.c:1499: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
readline.c:1499: error: for each function it appears in.)
make[2]: *** [readline.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/readline/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error. I solved it by using this command:

`rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-readline-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.4`

just use readline installed by homebrew, see more at https://rvm.io/packages/readline/

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are already using rvm and having problem with readline package
take a look at this instructions:

https://rvm.io/packages/readline/

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed readline package?

Try install 1.9.3-p194 (not p125) with latest RVM stable branch, which does not require the osx patch the above output mention. Please carefully follow the steps I described in [the article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651670/issue-updating-ruby-on-mac-with-xcode-4-3-1/9651747#9651747) and if you still have issues, please provide the commands you ran also (in addition to the output.)

Comment: awesome. That worked. I seems that somehow 1.9.3-p125 didn't work for me. Thanks a ton

Answer (score -1):

Go with http://rvm.io which is probably the easiest and best way today to install Ruby on your computer. Others might suggest rbenv or homebrew or other packet managers. Those are probably fine too.