# Trouble Installing Ruby 1.9.2 on OSX - Readline and Make errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, makefile, installation

I keep getting these errors:

Error running 'make ', please read /Users/jason***/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p320/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
ls: /Users/jason***/.rvm/rubies/*/bin/ruby: No such file or directory

I've tried installing readline and making sure I have the latest GCC version.
This is the error log.

```
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -dynamic -bundle -o ../../../.ext/x86_64-darwin11.3.0/racc/cparse.bundle cparse.o -L. -L../../.. -L/Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/usr/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace  -lruby.1.9.1  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc 
compiling readline
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -I. -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin11.3.0 -I../.././include -I../.././ext/readline -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\" -I/Users/jasonvdm/.rvm/usr/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long  -fno-common -pipe  -o readline.o -c readline.c
readline.c: In function ‘username_completion_proc_call’:
readline.c:1386: error: ‘username_completion_function’ undeclared (first use in this function)
readline.c:1386: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
readline.c:1386: error: for each function it appears in.)
make[1]: *** [readline.o] Error 1
make: *** [mkmain.sh] Error 1
```

Comment: Did you install Xcode and the command line tools?

Comment: Yes, I have Xcode and the command line tools that you get after registering as a developer.

Comment: I'm trying to install again for work, this time 1.9.2p180. Your fix isn't showing up, not sure why. Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you compiling Readline from source? It might be less painful to compile and install Readline via [**Homebrew**](https://brew.sh/), assuming that you have at least one working version of Ruby on your system.

Once you've done that, you can try the RVM install of Ruby 1.9.2 again, and it should skip the Readline compilation step.

**Updated in response to comment:**

So you *are* using a Homebrew installed Readline. In that case, find out where the new (less broken) Readline libs are installed, and try passing the location of *that* version of Readline to the RVM install process. Something like:

> rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p320 -C
> --with-readline-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1

Clearly, your directory will be slightly different the one in my example.

Comment: Ah, so you are. In that case, I've revised my answer to reflect this new piece of information ;-)

Comment: Spotlight finds two readline folders, both of which are in the ruby1.9.3 folder in my downloads folder. Is this correct? One is under test, and the other is under ext.

Comment: If you want to use the Homebrew readline, it will be installed somewhere under /usr/local/Cellar – Use the terminal to have a look around in there... Spotlight won't index these hidden UNIX directories, so it won't show up in search results on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using RVM, read the procedures in [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651670/issue-updating-ruby-on-mac-with-xcode-4-3-1/9651747#9651747).

You'd better install the readline library with `rvm pkg` command.